# Jenkins Build on push option is not appearing

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using jenkins version 1.579 and I have installed git plugin 2.2.5 on it , I have successfully build my project but when i try to configure build triggers, I get three options, I am not getting the option to build on push, Is there anything which i am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for a while i got the answer, we need to configure git hooks file specifically post-receive, This must be created in .git/hooks directory. Copy paste following line to post-receive file in hooks directory

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://<YOUR HOST>/git/notifyCommit?url=<Your Git Repo address>
```

You are good to go now, This post-receive file will notify the jenkins server, Whenever someone pushes code, Special note post-receive will work only on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Install github plugin rather than git plugin. Jenkins will install the other required plugins automatically. After this, you will get the option to build on push.

Comment: I am using git so i wanted the solution for git not github anyways i have found the solution